# How can i use html2pdf with crontab?

Tags: html2pdf

I have to create a daily crontab to send a pdf list to an email address.
The script works fine by calling from a browser, but not in a crontab
I know that is a path problem but anything works (relative path, full url).
Can you help me ? Thank you

```
<?php
$url= ????
include("$url/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php");
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output('$url/pdf/list.pdf',F);
```

?>

Comment: look in the error log ('/var/log/messages'  ??). The crontab runs under a different user , and the webserver probably runs under a diferent user too.... One of these users (the crontab user) seems to not have enough rights? (depending on the actual error message that is logged somewhere.....)

Comment: Get this error :
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'HTML2PDF' not found in /home/bibe9881/charenbaie.domain.fr/cron.php:74 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/bibe9881/charenbaie.domain.fr/cron.php on line 74

$url=charenbaie.domain.fr and exists